# How to make the minipage width adjust to available margins?

Tags: margins, enumerate, indentation, itemize, minipage

I'd like to place a minipage inside an enumerate/itemize environment and it respecting the right margin of the page, as `{\textwidth}` makes it go over the margin, is there any way to do this other than manually checking the exact length available for text? Maybe some way to substract the indent value from the `\textwidth`

Also, it would be great if it worked with the same command for multiple nested enumerates, as I'm currently using this command for the items on my enumerates:

```
\newcommand{\ej}[1]{
\item \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
{#1}

\end{minipage} }
```

Thanks!

Comment: It should work with `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\linewidth` in the place of \textwidth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{itemize}
    \item \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
            \lipsum[12]
        \end{minipage}
    \item \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
            \lipsum[13]
        \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\overfullrule=5pt
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}
    \item \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftmargin-\parindent\relax}
            {\lipsum[1]}
        \end{minipage}
    \item \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftmargin-\parindent\relax}
            {\lipsum[2]}
        \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\linewidth` is easier

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you're right!